# If statement not being executed/reached

Tags: javascript, math, if-statement, web

The JavaScript code below is attempting to calculate values associated with right-angled triangles by using the Pythagorean theorem.  I'm having a problem with the part detecting various combinations of inputs which is performed prior to executing the calculations.  It's just a series of `if` statements, and they're all very similar, but the last one won't execute.

[I made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t13qgL83/1/), in case some of you would like to mess around with the code.

Here's the function I'm having trouble with:

```
function drawNumbers() {
    if(cathetusAKnown) {
        cathetusA.value = cathetusANumber;
    }

    if(cathetusBKnown) {
        cathetusB.value = cathetusBNumber;
    }

    if(hypotenuseKnown) {
        hypotenuse.value = hypotenuseNumber;
    }

    if(angleAKnown) {
        angleA.value = angleANumber;
    }

    if(angleBKnown) {
        angleB.value = angleBNumber;
    }
}

function calculate() {
    updateNumbers(); 

    //If CathetusA and B are known, calculate the rest
    if(cathetusAKnown && cathetusBKnown) {
        if(!hypotenuseKnown) {
            calcHypotenuse();
        }

        if(!angleAKnown) {
            calcAngleA();
        }

        if(!angleBKnown) {
            calcAngleB();
        }
    }

    //If CathetusA and the hypotenuse are known, calculate the rest
    if(cathetusAKnown && hypotenuseKnown) {
        if (!cathetusBKnown) {
            calcCathetusB();
        }

        if(!angleAKnown) {
            calcAngleA();
        }

        if(!angleBKnown) {
            calcAngleB();
        }
    }

    //If CathetusB and the hypotenuse are known, calculate the rest
    if(cathetusBKnown && hypotenuseKnown) {
        if (!cathetusAKnown) {
            calcCathetusA();
        }

        if(!angleAKnown) {
            calcAngleA();
        }

        if(!angleBKnown) {
            calcAngleB();
        }
    }

    drawNumbers();
}
```

Comment: Maybe the second-to-last one throws an exception? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I've tried looking in Chrome's JS console, but as far as i can see, i'm not getting any errors..

Comment: How can you possibly tell which fields are the givens and which ones are the unknowns, especially when hitting "Calculate!" a second time?

Comment: That is a great question. I honestly didn't think of that.
I will fix that immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last case (computing cathetus A given cathetus B and hypotenuse) is sort of ok but the formula is wrong.

Given that `hyp² = a² + b²` you know that `a = sqrt(hyp² - b²)` and instead you're computing the opposite (`sqrt(b² - hyp²)`) this will result in `NaN` because you'll be taking the square root of a negative number.

Another error is also present in the other similar case (it doesn't gives a `NaN` but the result is wrong because you're **adding** the square of hypotenuse and the square of cathetus.

Comment: Thanks! I must've overlooked this! I'm such an idiot, lol.
What do you refer to with "The other similar case"?

Comment: @Elias: computing cathetus B given cathetus A and hypotenuse. You're using an addition instead of a subtraction (hyp-cat).

Comment: Ah, i see. I must've been very sleepy when i made this..
Well, thanks for the help!